# I need help regarding Selenium and chrome webdrivers. An error pops up in my CommandPrompt and i am not sure how to solve it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Python and Selenium and working on Windows.
I am currently learning a course in Udemy about Selenium and Python in order to create an automated script aka a web bot

Steps in the lecture:

1. Create a virtual environment and install pip in it
2. Activating the virtual environment
3. Running `Python.exe`
4. Types `import selenium import webdriver`'
5. Types browser = `webdriver.Chrome()`
6. Chrome browser opens. But at the same time, it gives this error message:

   DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57721/devtools/browser/714e788a-2c6a-452b-b89f-403520a5ab75

> > > [17820:23420:1024/073800.031:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
> > > [17820:23420:1024/073800.032:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
> > > [17820:20848:1024/073800.033:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(160)] Device descriptor parsing error.
> > > [17820:20848:1024/073800.034:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [07:38:00.034] USB: usb_device_win.cc:93 Failed to read descriptors from \?\usb#vid_046d&pid_c332#198b38733838#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}.
> > > [17820:23420:1024/073800.033:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
> > > [17820:20848:1024/073800.038:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [07:38:00.038] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
> > > [17820:20848:1024/073800.039:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [07:38:00.038] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
> > > [17820:23420:1024/073800.324:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
> > > [12304:24324:1024/073956.924:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

7. I am still able to browser.get('webpages') but it gives more error messages like

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "", line 1, in 
   File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in get
   self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
   File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
   self.error_handler.check_response(response)
   File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
   (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.54)
   Stacktrace:
   Backtrace:
   Ordinal0 [0x00E43AB3+2505395]
   Ordinal0 [0x00DDAE41+2076225]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CE2498+1057944]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CDF0A1+1044641]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CD52C2+1004226]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CD5EC2+1007298]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CD550A+1004810]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CD4BC8+1002440]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CD3D5D+998749]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CD4016+999446]
   Ordinal0 [0x00CE3A6A+1063530]
   Ordinal0 [0x00D356ED+1398509]
   Ordinal0 [0x00D259F3+1333747]
   Ordinal0 [0x00D35168+1397096]
   Ordinal0 [0x00D258BB+1333435]
   Ordinal0 [0x00D023E4+1188836]
   Ordinal0 [0x00D0323F+1192511]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x00FCCB36+1554566]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x01074A0C+2242396]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x00ED0E0B+523099]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x00ECFEB0+519168]
   Ordinal0 [0x00DE02FD+2097917]
   Ordinal0 [0x00DE4388+2114440]
   Ordinal0 [0x00DE44C2+2114754]
   Ordinal0 [0x00DEE041+2154561]
   BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76F3FA29+25]
   RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77107A9E+286]
   RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77107A6E+238]
8. Would really appreciate if someone can explain what I can do to resolve this error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not error messages. I get them all the time and nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

These are **not** error messages.

The '**Traceback**' is a containing the function calls made in your code at a specific point.

They should not interfere with your code.

An error would be explictly stated: for e.g.

AttributeError
ImportError
IndexError
KeyError
NameError
SyntaxError
TypeError
ValueError